# Computing the sum of two rows with different id in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I have a problem regarding computing the sum of rows in MySQL with a different id.
Here is my table structure:

Table Orders

```
---------------------------
Transaction Id          Name
---------------------------
1                    John
2                    Jim
3                    Erick
4                    John
---------------------------
```

Table Details

```
---------------------------
Customer Id         Amount
---------------------------
1                    10.00
1                    20.00
2                    40.00
3                     5.00
3                     5.00
1                    50.00
---------------------------
```

I have tried joining the tables but the result only shows the total sum of all the rows with the same id.:

```
---------------------------------
Name                 Total Amount
---------------------------------
John                     80.00
Jim                      40.00
Erick                    10.00
---------------------------------
```

What I want to show on the result the per transaction :

```
----------------------------------
Name                 Total Amount
----------------------------------
John                 30.00
Jim                  40.00
Erick                10.00
John                 50.00
----------------------------------
```

Hope anyone can help me. Thank you

Comment: Why are there two rows for `John` in the result? How is it supposed to know which details should be in which row?

Comment: You need an `order_id` column in both tables to distinguish them.

Comment: And the customer name shouldn't be in the `Orders` table, it should be in the `Customers` table.

Comment: John has two different transactions that's why he there 2 times.

Comment: But there's no transaction ID, so how can you tell which detail is in which transaction?

Comment: I updated the table good sir. im sorry. im new to this kind of problem and i cant seems to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an Order ID in the Orders table, and that should be used as the foreign key in Details. Your tables should look like this:

Table Orders

```
-----------------------------
Customer Id          Order ID
-----------------------------
1                    1
2                    2
3                    3
1                    4
---------------------------
```

Table Details

```
---------------------------
Order Id             Amount
---------------------------
1                    10.00
1                    20.00
2                    40.00
3                     5.00
3                     5.00
4                    50.00
---------------------------
```

Table Customers

```
---------------------
Customer Id     Name
1               John
2               Jim
3               Erick
--------------------
```

And then the query to get your results is:

```
SELECT o.order_id, c.name, SUM(d.amount) AS total
FROM orders AS o
JOIN customers AS c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN details AS d ON o.order_id = d.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id, c.name
```

Comment: Youre a life saver good sir. Thank you. More power to you. God bless